# fclose(in) segmentation faulting

Tags: c

I have reduced the program with comments, down to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE * in;
    in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fclose(in);
    fprintf(stderr, "clear **** \n");
    return(0);
 }
```

yet it still segfaults. Output is:

```
clear
Segmentation Fault
```

I know it's fclose(in) that's causing the problem, I just don't know why. For whatever reason, fclose(out) works perfectly fine.

Comment: What are you passing on the command line?  If the fopen() call fails, you will be calling fclose(NULL), essentially.

Comment: And "they" say exceptions are a bad thing ... :-)

Comment: Always check return values of functions. File IO fails a lot...

Comment: The `****` are *not* printed?

Answer (score 3):

First thing you should do is something like:

```
in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (in == NULL)
    printf ("Could not open file '%s'\n" argv[1]);
else
    fclose(in);
```

There's no guarantee in your original code that the `fopen` is actually working, in which case it will return NULL and the `fclose` will not be defined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! This narrowed it down for me alot.